# Tcl - How to Add Text after last character through regex?

Tags: regex, linux, unix, tcl, tk-toolkit

I need a tip, tip or suggestion followed by some example of how I can add an extension in *.txt* format after the last character of a variable's output line.

**For example:**

```
set txt " ONLINE ENGLISH COURSE - LESSON 5 "

set result [concat "$txt" .txt]
```

**Print:**

[image]

> Note that **there is space** in the *start*, *means* and *fin* of the variable phrase (*txt*). What must be maintained are the spaces of the *start* and *means*. But replace the last space after the end of the sentence, with the format of the extension [.txt].

With the built-in `concat` method of `Tcl`, it does not achieve the desired effect.

The expected result was something like this:

```
ONLINE ENGLISH COURSE - LESSON 5.txt
```

---

I know I could remove spaces with `string map` but I don't know how to remove just the last occurrence on the line.

And otherwise I don’t know how to remove the last space to add the text [.txt]

If anyone can point me to one or more solutions, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set result "[string trimright $txt].txt"
```

or

```
set result [regsub {\s*$} $txt ".txt"]
```

Comment: In 8.6, there's also `string cat $txt ".txt"`.